# monaca でアプリ内課金

Tags: monaca, アプリ内課金

monacaで、AndroidのIn-app-Billingを使用したアプリ内課金をおこないたいと考えているのですが、可能なのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました
Cordovaプラグインでアプリ内課金を実装しました

Monacaでアプリ内課金を実現するには、有料プランに加入し、Cordobaプラグインを導入すればよいようでした

Monacaが提供する有料プラグインもあるようです